# Windows WebBrowser Control stopped post back

Tags: asp.net, webbrowser-control, reportviewer, xbap

I am working on a large XBap application which is using a web browser control to view a SQL report asp.net web app. With certain javascript operations, the controls stopped functioning (repeatable). e.g. a button still responds to hover and click but not validation and post back. Simple dropdown still work but not the ones with check boxes as the entries.

Then after certain operations, the report page will function again.

I tried programmatically to force the browser control to refresh, focus, enable, etc. Nothing worked. I guess javascript stopped working somehow. But there is no way to influence it with web browser control.

Comment: If you provide a fiddle to demonstrate the issue, or a link to the web application (better make it a test instance), others may be able to better help.

Comment: Sorry, our application is too big and i am not able to reproduce the problem with a simple demo. With further testing. I found that the webbrowser control lost keydown event when not working and keydown event firing again when the report application functioning again. But the parent control always got keydown events. To rebuild  logical tree does not help either.

Comment: Further trying confirmed that the logical and visual trees are fine although even tunneling failed reach webbrowser control. Microsoft mentioned that the input of webbrowser control is working on a separate thread because it is a true activeX control. I sense some how the input thread was pushed out of reach of the parent container control. But I don't know what to do about it.